# c# - adding javascript function from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

```
DBDataSet.tblAdsDataTable dtAds = client.getAdsDate(ref errCode, AdsType, AdsSlot, Country);
        string ss = "";
        string aa = "";
        if (dtAds.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DBDataSet.tblAdsRow dr in dtAds)
            {
                DateTime date = dr.AdsDate;
                string AdsDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                ss += '"' + AdsDate + '"' +",";  
                aa = ss.TrimEnd(','); // equal to "01/01/2018","02/01/2018"

                string jquery = "var naArray = ["+ aa +"];";;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key","<script>" + jquery + "</script>");
            }
        }
```

Hi, from the code above, i would want to add javascript in code behind like `<script> var naArray = ["01/01/2018","02/01/2018"];</script>`. However, when i execute, it become `<script> var naArray = ["01/01/2018"]; <script>` which "02/01/2018" is missing in the array. Appreciate if anyone can help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I dont see any code that is making up the 02/01/2018 date in your sample above? You have only used AdsDate

Comment: Hi @PrateekShrivastava, i have edited my code.

Comment: aa = ss.TrimEnd(','); // equal to "01/01/2018","02/01/2018"

Can you explain this code?

Comment: The date is retrieve from datatable & i want to add each date into array in the javascript

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer, aa = ss.TrimEnd(','); if not adding this, it will become "01/01/2018","02/01/2018", mean adding a "," behind

Comment: In each iteration you are overriding aa.

Comment: Adding JavaScript from code behind looks like cancer. Make sure you have valid reasons for doing so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting value to jquery variable is inside the foreach loop. It should be outside of the loop. Try updating your code as below.

```
DBDataSet.tblAdsDataTable dtAds = client.getAdsDate(ref errCode, AdsType, AdsSlot, Country);
string ss = "";
string aa = "";
if (dtAds.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DBDataSet.tblAdsRow dr in dtAds)
    {
        DateTime date = dr.AdsDate;
        string AdsDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        ss += '"' + AdsDate + '"' +",";                  
    }
    aa = ss.TrimEnd(','); // equal to "01/01/2018","02/01/2018"
    string jquery = "var naArray = ["+ aa +"];";;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key","<script>" + jquery + "</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string aa = "";

        foreach (DBDataSet.tblAdsRow dr in dtAds)
        {
            DateTime date = dr.AdsDate;
            string AdsDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            aa += '"' + AdsDate + '"' + ","; // equal to "01/01/2018","02/01/2018"
        }

        aa = aa.TrimEnd(',');
```

Attach javascript outside your loop. Your value is changing in each iteration.